# Detecting operator Set in Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Here is a typical issue: `Simplify[x + y, x = y]` produces `2 True`.

Is there a way to detect operator `Set` in assumptions and issue a warning?

**Update:** 
As Mr.Wizard suggested it is possible to write a wrapper for `Simplify` that will check the second argument. But since there are many [built-in functions which use assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/806) it will be cumbersome to overload them all. Maybe there is a more simple way?

Comment: Look up `$Pre` and `$PreRead`

Comment: rm-rf gave you the best advice I think. Consider putting some function in `$Pre` which checks for whatever list of patterns you create of stuff you want to be warned about.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand the spirit of your question.  My apologies of this answer is obvious to you and you intended something else.

```
Simplify::badSet = "Function Set used in assumptions where is likely in error.";

SetAttributes[mySimplify, HoldAll];

mySimplify[expr_, assum_] :=
  Message[Simplify::badSet] /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated@assum, Set]

mySimplify[else__] := Simplify[else]
```

Now:

```
mySimplify[x + y, x = a]
```

> Simplify::badSet: Set used in assumptions where is likely in error. >>

You could overload `Simplify` itself if you are comfortable with such things.  You'll want to be familiar with the [Villegas-Gayley method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/618728) of you choose that path.

Comment: This made me think about `SyntaxInformation`'s "ColorEqualSigns" option, only to find that it isn't working (on my system, v8 or v9) other than for the first argument

Comment: Try `"ColorEqualSigns" /. SyntaxInformation /@ {And, For, Implies, Nand, Nor, Not, Or, Which, Xor}`. +1 btw. In >v8 that gives `{All, {2, 2}, All, All, All, All, All, Odd, All}`. Try it with a custom function, it doesn't work either

Comment: @Rojo same result in v7: `{All, {2, 2}, All, All, All, All, All, Odd, All}`

Comment: And it also doesn't work? `And[x=4, y=6]` only colours red the first `=`?

Comment: @Rojo sorry; that's the same too.

Comment: This is a possible workaround. But it will require to overload a lot of functions.

Comment: @Nick How else would you target this warning or interception other than to overload functions *or* list all functions explicitly in a pattern (for e.g. `$Pre`)?

Answer (score 2):

@rm-rf suggested somtething along these lines I believe

```
$cancelOnSyntaxError = False;

syntaxCheckingRules = {i : HoldPattern[Simplify[_, _ = _]] :> 
    "Equal in " <> ToString@HoldForm@i};

fixRules[lhs_ :> rhs_] := 
  lhs :> Block[{}, (Print@rhs; dontEval = True) /; True];

$Pre = Function[code,
       Block[{dontEval = False},
        Unevaluated[code] /. fixRules /@ syntaxCheckingRules;
        If[! dontEval || ! $cancelOnSyntaxError, code, $Canceled]
    ], HoldAllComplete];
```

Too add more checks, append to `syntaxCheckingRules` the pattern of the syntax error and the string you want to be displayed as output.

With that set

```
Simplify[2, x = 4]
```

prints a warning message