# What is ColorEqualSigns and how does one use it?

Tags: bugs, syntax-highlighting

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and persists in 13.3**

---

I'm setting up the [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) for a package I'm writing and I'm struggling to understand what the `"ColorEqualSigns"` property is supposed to do, how one is meant to use it, and whether it works at all.

From what I can tell, it is meant to colour equal signs (i.e. `=`) red, in positions where it is likely that the intended operator is [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html), i.e. `==`, instead of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html). This includes positions that normally take equations (like in [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)) or logical tests (like in [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html)). Is this a correct understanding of the expected behaviour?

However, I'm having trouble getting the Front End to reproduce this behaviour, both for my own functions and for the in-built ones.

For my own functions, code like

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ColorEqualSigns" -> {1, 2}};
f[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3]
```

only marks the first one as an error:

[image]

To do the system-defined functions, one can get a comprehensive list by running

```
list = Select[
  Table[
   {symbol, SyntaxInformation[ToExpression[symbol]]}
   , {symbol, Names["System`*"]}]
  , (("ColorEqualSigns" /. #[[2]]) =!= "ColorEqualSigns") &]
```

the output of which is nicely formatted by `TableForm[{#1, {"ColorEqualSigns"} /. #2} & @@@ list]`.

```
And             All
DSolve          1   1
For             2   2
If              1   1
Implies         All
Nand            All
NDSolve         1   1
NDSolveValue    1   1
Nor             All
Not             All
NRoots          1   1
NSolve          1   1
Or              All
Reduce          1   1
Solve           1   1
SolveAlways     1   1
Which           Odd
While           1   1
Xor             All
```

From these, only `If` and `While` seem to work as intended. As a test, see the syntax colouring on the following:

```
And[a = 1, b = 2]
DSolve[y'[x] = y[x], y, x]
For[i = 0, i = 5, i++, Print[i]]
If[i = j, a, b]
Implies[a = b, c = d]
Nand[a = 1, b = 2]
NDSolve[y'[x] = y[x], y, x]
DSolveValue[{y'[x] = y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] = 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
Nor[a = 1, b = 2]
Not[a = 1]
NRoots[1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3 = 0, x]
NSolve[x^5 - 2 x + 3 = 0, x]
Or[a = 1, b = 2]
Reduce[x^2 - y^3 = 1, {x, y}]
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 = 0, x]
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 = 0, x]
Which[a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6]
While[n = 4, n++]
Xor[a = 1, b = 2]
```

which render on my machine (MM 11.0.0, 10.3.0, 10.1.0 and 9.0.1 over Ubuntu) as

[image]

Note that e.g. the second equals sign in `And[a = 1, b = 2]` is not marked as erroneous, which is inconsistent with the rule `"ColorEqualSigns" -> All` in `SyntaxInformation[All]`. This is present at least since early 2013, as [pointed out in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18398/detecting-operator-set-in-assumptions#comment55743_18399).

Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: I am not a Wolfram insider so I cannot answer this question but it certainly doesn't *appear* to be working as intended.

Comment: Appears the same way on Windows. Probably a bug.

Answer (score 7):

So I delved into this as part of a new effort to review things like `SyntaxInformation`, function templates, and so forth.  Too early to say what will come of this, but feel free to send requests.

As for the specific issue of "ColorEqualSigns".  First, how it's supposed to work.  The allowed values (currently) are

```
All
None
Odd  (* see below *)
Even (* see below *)
pos_Integer
{minpos_Integer,maxpos_Integer}
```

All of these (are supposed to) have the more or less obvious meanings.  But I've identified mutliple issues I have reported internally.

1. The FE is expecting the values `` System`Odd `` and `` System`Even ``, but of course there are no such symbols.  Probably just an oversight when first created--these should have been `OddQ` and `EvenQ`. Nobody noticed since only one function uses these values, namely `Which`.  I would recommend just unprotecting `Which` and putting `` System`Odd `` as a workaround, except for:
2. For some reason, the coloring is only active in the first argument.  So if your spec includes the first position, you'll see it there, but not elsewhere.  If the spec doesn't include 1, you won't see it anywhere. This is obviously a bug.  It's a bit embarassing it wasn't noticed internally earlier.
3. The coloring requires that the LHS be a single token.  Compare the appearance of `Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 = 0, x]` and `Solve[0 = x^2 + a x + 1, x]`.  This is arguably not a bug if you think of this feature descending from things like `If[test,...]`.  `If[x=0,...]` is valid syntax which will quietly do the wrong thing in all cases.  `If[x^2+2x+1=0,...]` will give you a message.  Still, I feel this is not keeping with the spirit of this option and I have reported this as a bug.
4. It doesn't enter lists and check equal signs inside.  It's certainly a limitation, but it's not obviously wrong.  And certainly, how many levels down does it check?  Is it worth the development cost and/or performance cost?  I'm not saying it wouldn't be nice to do this (I would like it), but this definitely more in the "feature request" than "bug fix" category.

So now it is reported and might actually be fixed.  I can't say when, will the first is obviously easy, I don't know enough about the code to even guess at the difficulty of the others.  I'll try to keep this updated as I get news.

Comment: It's good to see this one getting done attention =).