# Is it possible to make a custom syntax coloring for "=", "==", and "==="?

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

I have made this type mistake so many times:

```
Which[a=b,expr1,True,expr2]
```

as opposed to the intended but still correct syntax

```
Which[a==b,expr1,True,expr2]
```

And, the mistake doesn't jump out at me--especially when there are more than several lines of code.  Syntax coloring would help me identify the mistake quickly.

*Is it possible to make a custom syntax coloring for "=", "==", and "==="?*

Comment: `SyntaxInformation[Which]` seems to indicate that equal signs of odd-index arguments should be colored. But they're not. The setting `"ColorEqualSigns" -> OddQ` is not documented and seems not to work. A bug? Ask WRI.

Comment: Possible duplicate?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59755/what-is-colorequalsigns-and-how-does-one-use-it -- It certainly implies that you're out of luck. Unless there's a hack around the bug.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157554/4999), ``"ColorEqualSigns" -> System`Odd`` should color `=` at odd-index arguments, but it colors only the first argument. (So it's a known bug since 2017.)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2.  Useful to know that this is potentially interesting enough that somebody wanted it in 2017.  Fingers crossed for a future release.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this should be a hard fix because == already gets redisplayed as a contracted symbol.

Comment: If more people ask for it to be fixed, that will make it seem more valuable to WRI to fix it.

Comment: You may find some other (ie. not by changing the colors) feasible solutions to your problem in [Detecting operator Set in Assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18398/detecting-operator-set-in-assumptions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 1. Syntax Coloring (partially working)

Under menu `Edit > Preferences > Appearance > Syntax Coloring > Errors and Warnings`, turn on `Possible unwanted assignments`. This will make `=` in `Solve` red.

[image]

However, as explained by [@Itai Seggev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157554/75628), this doesn't work for `Which` due to a bug. It can be fixed, but it will unfortunately work only for the first argument (which is apparently also a known but not yet fixed bug):

```
Unprotect[Which];
SyntaxInformation[Which] = SyntaxInformation[Which] /.
  ("ColorEqualSigns" -> _) -> ("ColorEqualSigns" -> System`Odd);
Protect[Which];
```

[image]

### 2. Operator Rendering

For versions 12.3.1+, you can use `OperatorRenderings` to set more distinct characters for `Set`, `Equal` and `SameQ`. There is a whole variety of interesting [Unicode symbols](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Sm) that resemble `=`, such as `＝ ﹦ ⩶ ≝ ⌯ ⩸`. You can probably find your own combination of symbols which will help you in easier differentiation between them.

```
opR = AbsoluteCurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}];
opR["="] = "≜";
opR["=="] = "≡";
opR["==="] = "≣";
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}] = opR;
```

[image: Animation of typing]

Comment: Thanks. Not just solve, but also this:  `Which[a = b, a, True, b]`  The Solve example wasn't a good example of what I wanted--I'll edit  Would you mind deleting your answer so the question gets attention?

Comment: I have edited the answer so that it more clearly shows its flaws. However, I believe it still does partially answer your question. Obviously, you have every right to downvote it or/and not accept it :) (Or give a bounty to the question for more attention ...)

Comment: Excellent! Accepted as answered. Thanks.